# C# code to serialize plain-old-CLR-objects to JSON

Tags: c#, json, .net-3.5, serialization, poco

Within an ASP.NET application, I'd like to serialize a collection of plain-old-CLR-objects (POCO) to a JSON string, which will then be sent down to the client as part of a web response.

Is there a light-weight C# library that does this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try [`DataContractJsonSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.aspx):

> Serializes objects to the JavaScript
>   Object Notation (JSON) and
>   deserializes JSON data to objects.
>
> Use the DataContractJsonSerializer
>   class to serialize instances of a type
>   into a JSON document and to
>   deserialize a JSON document into an
>   instance of a type. For example, you
>   can create a type named Person with
>   properties that contain essential
>   data, such as a name and address. You
>   can then create and manipulate an
>   instance of the Person class and write
>   all of its property values in a JSON
>   document for later retrieval. This
>   JSON document can later be
>   deserialized into the Person class or
>   another class with an equivalent data
>   contract.

Answer (score 26):

Yes, I've had a lot of success with [JSON.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx).

As an example from the web page:

```
Product product = new Product();
product.Name = "Apple";
product.Expiry = new DateTime(2008, 12, 28);
product.Price = 3.99M;
product.Sizes = new string[] { "Small", "Medium", "Large" };

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(product);
```